# error in Request for Google Cloud Speech API request

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I'm getting this error when I make my request to the Google Cloud Speech API:
"error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT

My curl command looks like this:
curl -s -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxx" \https://speech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/speech:syncrecognize -d @sync-request.json

and my config file like this:

```
      {
  'config': {
      'encoding':'FLAC',
      'sampleRate': 16000,
      'languageCode': 'de-DE'
  },
  'audio': {
      'uri':'https://storage.googleapis.com/project_name/xxxx_Ger16.flac'
  }
}
```

What is missing or invalid in the request? Thanks.

Comment: I finally solved this: it was the uri. It needed to be gs://project_name etc.

Answer (score 7):

The error message received suggests a property you've provided in your JSON request body is not valid.  As you've confirmed in your comment, the `audio.uri` value for Cloud Storage resources should match the pattern **gs://bucket_name/object_name**.

The `audio` object in the request body of type [`RecognitionAudio`](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionAudio).  The documentation for this confirms your findings.

Comment: Yep. Stupid of me to miss this. I just assumed an http:// url would work. Moved files to GS and changed the URL to gs:// and bam! It worked. Spent 2 hours trying to debug this. Thanks!